# Why use masked attention in the second to 6th decoder blocks during training

Tags: transformer, attention

For the first block we have access to all the output tokens, so we will have to use masked self-attention. After that in the first decoder block, we have encoder-decoder attention, which will bring some information about the future tokens, but this information is not cheating because model is only seeing future tokens in input language (let's say the transformer is translating from one to another language). So the final output of the first decoder block might have some features from the future token but they will be from the input language and this can help the model decode the current word better. So is there a reason to mask from second to 6th decoder block that I am missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.